# Ways to set thumbnail for an RSS feed item

Tags: rss

Many feed readers seem to use different tags for thumbnails. What are some common ways of specifying thumbnails?

So far, I know about the `enclosure` tag, the `media:thumbnail` tag, embedding images directly in the item description, and using the `og:image` meta tag. What are ways are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tehcnically, the *only* way to do it with pure RSS is `<enclosure>`. Now, the greatness of RSS is that it's (almost) XML, which means that you can extended with namespaces... whether they are existing namespaces (like [MediaRSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_RSS)) or completely custom ones.

As to what you should do:

1. try to avoid creating your own namespace because it's unlikely everyone else will do the work to support it.
2. Use MediaRSS: (`media:thumbnail`) specifically if you need it for more than just the thumbnail (like a larger image, or other media elements).
3. If you only need `<enclosure>` then, just use plain RSS: simpler is better!